# How to make sure sharedpreferences are cleaned when saved

Tags: android

In an Android app I let the user edit his preferences by running a class which  extends PreferenceActivity.
In res\xml I have a file - preferences.xml - which has an xml-description of which fields the user can configure. Things like usernames and passwords. A sample snippet:

```
<EditTextPreference android:name="User Name"
android:summary="Name in Your Name/Company format"
android:defaultValue="" android:title="Login name" android:key="userName" 
android:id="@+id/userName"/>

<EditTextPreference android:name="Password"
android:summary="Your web password" android:defaultValue=""
android:title="Login password" android:password="true" android:key="userPassword" 
android:id="@+id/userPassword"/>
```

Things are working as expected. From my main app code I can access the values that the user has configured.

There is one thing that I hope to get some good advice on how to handle: Removing leading and trailing blank spaces in the preferences-values.

By user error or because of helpful keyboard apps, sometimes users enter an extra blank character in EditTextPreferences fields. Either as the first or the last character.

I would prefer if such obvious typing errors could be removed no later than when the user exits the PreferenceActivity.
I would like to get suggestions on a good way of cleaning up the user's preferences.

Comment: Does calling trim() on all user input will work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `String.trim()` on the values provided by the user, before saving them to prefs. The trim() method removes all white-space characters from the front and end of the input string.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I hope you can clarify something for me though. Because I am using the PreferencesActivity, I don't actively save every preference-value myself. The saving must somehow be hidden in abstraction layers in the combination of the PreferencesActivity and the xml file. So how do you suggest that I access every single value of the preferences in order to do the String.trim() ?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I missed that. I'd extend EditTextPreference to build your own TrimmedEditTextPreference and override setText() to do the trim() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

Comment: To try out your suggestion I have created an new Class: public class TrimmedEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference. All it contains right now are three constructors. I haven't started yet looked at setText(). In my preferences.xml I have then changed one of the entries from being of the type EditTextPreference to being TrimmedEditTextPreference. When I run the app in the simulator and open the Preferences, it Force Closes. In logcat I get  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.preference.TrimmedEditTextPreference in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44dac878

Comment: In the XML you need to use a fully qualified reference to your class, like com.blah.TrimmedEditTextPreference

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me. Thanks! All I did was to re-create the three constructors and then the setText method. the setText only has one line of code: super.setText(text.trim())

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Ollie C's comment, the current EditTextPreference code for onDialogClosed looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

    if (positiveResult) {
        String value = mEditText.getText().toString();
        if (callChangeListener(value)) {
            setText(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This calls the change listener with the original value.  Instead of modifying setText, I'd recommend doing something like this in your child class:

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult)
{
    String text = getEditText().getText().toString();
    getEditText().setText(text.trim());

    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
}
```